# Can't change background colour in Dreamweaver

Tags: html, background-color, dreamweaver

I'm creating a newsletter email in Dreamweaver, I'm almost done but I can't change the background(or body I suppose). I tried entering using the color picker tool, but nothing changed, it's still the same color as before.

**p.s** I can't show the code, whenever I try to post it, I get a red box saying that it appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code, so I'll just send a screenshot of the code.

https://i.gyazo.com/558639f136aa691c08b947dc2b9fc3da.png

Comment: What kind of color you want to change ?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to change a color of background use one method. Because in your code you  messed up. You have used both inline and internal stlying.Since I didn't see your all codes I give you 2 solutions.

**HTML code**

```
<body>
  <table <!-- your table properties goes here--> >
  </table>
</body>
```

**CSS code**

```
body{
   background-color: #0aed05; /* Green*/
}
```

Or even it won't work.Check it out this one.

**HTML code**

```
<body id="body">
  <table <!-- your table properties goes here--> >
  </table>
</body>
```

**CSS code**

```
#body{
   background-color: #0aed05; /* Green*/
}
```